# Any way to add boundaries to my maze without a complete reaproach/recode?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I put this maze game together for a school project with the help from a few partner. I've gotten drawing on images to work, but my teacher is looking for some form of boundary/border preventing the user from skipping past walls. I'm not even sure if it's possible.

This is the block for individual images along with a short snippet of the Level selector buttons.

Note: These are just parts of the code arranged to show you guys the part I'm talking about. It's formatted differently in the actual file.

```
<li align="center" style="color:yellow"><div style="color:yellow">(Medium)    </div><input type="button" id="l2" value="Level 2" onClick="test2()"/>


<script>
 var img2 = new Image();
 function test2() {
 can.width = img2.width;
 can.height = img2.height;
 ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
}
img2.src = 'http://www.hereandabove.com/cgi-bin/maze?30+30+20+5+5+0+0+0+255+255+255.jpg';
</script>
```

Here is the code I am using to allow drawing on the images.

```
<canvas id="can1">

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('can1');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
 isDrawing = true;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
};
el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};
</script>
```

Comment: check the coordinates `e.offsetX, e.offsetY` in `onmousemove` before allowing `.lineTo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what your maze images look like it's a little difficult, but a very rudimentary solution would be to check the color of the image at the mouse cursor point, and depending on the color decide whether to keep drawing.

I've got some *mostly accurate* code below, the idea is in this case to get the color of the image at the position of the mouse cursor.  In this case I assume a black and white maze where the walls are black and movable area is white.  I check the color data to see that red is maxed out (this will only work if your walking area is a color where red is maxed out, like white, red, or yellow. For different colors adjust accordingly, but here rgbColorData is an array where 0 is red, 1 is green, and 2 is blue).  As long as the color determines it's movable, then you move.

Again, without the actual code it's hard to provide a perfect answer, but I'd go in this direction.

```
var rgbColorData = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data; 
if (rgbColorData[0] == 255) {
    isDrawing = true;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Currently looking into this method.